# Boost.Units and assignment operator with prefixes

Tags: c++, boost, boost-units

I am trying to get started with Boost.Units and facing the following issue:

```
#include <boost/units/quantity.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/si/prefixes.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/si/length.hpp>
using namespace boost::units::si;
using namespace boost::units;

int main()
{
    quantity<length> a(10.0 * centi * meter); //compiles fine
    quantity<length> b = 10.0 * centi * meter; //compiler error
}
```

The error, due to the templated nature of the library, is very long: `error: conversion from 'boost::units::multiply_typeof_helper<boost::units::quantity`...

Is this by design, or am I missing something?

Comment: There's no implicit conversion defined. This is on purpose.

Comment: A link to the FAQ: [Why are conversions explicit by default?](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_units/FAQ.html#boost_units.FAQ.ExplicitConversions)

Comment: Thank you, I see now. All conversions must be explicit in order to avoid unintended behaviour.